# Sub with multiple parameters not defined error

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to execute this sub it gives the error

> sub not defined

and it doesn't appear in the macros list.

The sub is in the personal workbook module (other subs in the same module work). If I delete the arguments and define `Sub dailytf()` it is recognized by VBA.

```vb
Sub dailytf(startingCell As Range, startDate As Date, endDate As Date) 
Dim count As Double
Dim lastDateAdded As Date

count = 0
lastDateAdded = startDate

Do
    lastDateAdded = DateAdd("d", count, lastDateAdded)
    startingCell = startingCell.Offset(0, count)
    startingCell.Value = lastDateAdded
    count = count + 1
Loop Until lastDateAdded = endDate

End Sub
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is now resolved thanks to ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to execute VBA don't know what parameters to pass. So it is not valid "macro". Make another helper sub and execute it like this:

```
Sub helper()
  Call dailytf(Range("A4"), "03/19/2023", "03/22/2023" )  
end Sub
```

Comment: Im gonna try this but is it normal that i tried to execute: dailytf range("A4"), "03/19/2023", "03/22/2023" in the immediate window and it gave me the error sub not defined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519832/vba-application-run-for-running-macros-with-parameters-stored-inside-an-excel-ce